# Why does ActiveRecord find_by return nil when using it together with select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I found the following kind of usage of ActiveRecord#find_by written in a Rails 4.1 project:

`booking = Booking.find_by(member_id: Member.where(id: 1).select(:id))`

However, this query returned nil after upgrading the project to Rails > 4.2.

In Rails 4.2 the above query generates the following SQL:

`SELECT  "bookings".* FROM "bookings" WHERE "bookings"."member_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["member_id", nil]]`

A 'Booking' belongs to a 'Member' and a 'Member' has many 'Booking'.

Does anyone know or see why? I would be interested in an explanation.

Replacing the select with pluck brings back the expected behavior:

`booking = Booking.find_by(member_id: Member.where(id: 1).pluck(:id))`

Generated query: `SELECT  "bookings".* FROM "bookings" WHERE "bookings"."member_id" = 1 LIMIT 1`

Edit: A member record with ID 1 exists in the database.

`Member.where(id: 1).select(:id)` returns the following result and SQL statement with Rails 4.2:

`=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Member id: 1>]>`

`SELECT "members"."id" FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]`

Comment: Mmmmm you switched the position of `where` and `find_by` and now I cannot reproduce it anymore. Are you sure the last edit is correct? the `Member.find_by(id: 1).select(:id)` returns nil always. The current form should just work, albeit being very inefficient (if you have the member-id, just use it immediately instead of retrieving _all the members_ with that id, and _selecting_ their id).

Comment: Thanks nathanvda for your comment. I only edited the last part of the question starting from "Edit:". `Member.where(id: 1).select(:id)` does return a ActiveRecord::Relation but combined with `Booking.find_by(member_id: Member.where(id: 1).select(:id))` the result is nil in Rails > 4.2 and that's my question.

Comment: Ah ok, must have misread then. I see it now, I can reproduce it as well. If I write `.find_by(member_id: Member.where(id: 1).select(:id))` I get `nil`. I do not understand since the implementation of `find_by` is just `where(*args).take`. If I use `where(..).first` or `where(...).take` it just works, but writing `find_by` with the same arguments invariably returns nil? Mmmmm interesting ...

Comment: I have the exact same findings, nathanvda. Mhhhh...

Answer (score -2):

Read this
[[Rails-ORM] find_by vs. where](https://medium.com/@derekfan/rails-find-by-vs-where-1c7814864e77)